# Windows package manager for local repository?

Tags: windows, package-management

I have a bunch of scripts that are used internally at my work. To distribute these I created a sort of repository and a front end script for it. It has worked okay for now, but I began to think there is probably something out there already for this. I have found a few things, but most package managers are for installing common windows applications. I need one that supports a local software repository that I can run on a server. I have found this: 
http://code.google.com/p/windows-package-manager/

Are there alternatives? Does anyone have an opinion on which is the best?

P.S. The scripts I have are perl/ruby that are packaged into standalone .exe's.